# Any way to get Request body in web automation testing with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm doing web automation testing by Selenium. There is a form in web page, and when the value of the form field is changed, click Submit button, requests sent out with the form values.

Now I want to know if there is any way that can capture the requests and get its request body, so I can verify if the body is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Mmh well you are sort of mixing backend and frontend testing there. There is no real way that I know of but in theory you could get the current page source code and check if that would build the correct request.

```
String source = driver.getPageSource();
```

But in my opinion that is not what you should be doing in your front end tests. This is messy and has no place in front end testing. Instead the web page's code should have its own tests. This makes sure that whatever code you are running inside of the page it is "in theory" valid if its tests are successful. Then you use Selenium to *only* check the front end - because that is what Selenium is for. You check that you are being redirected to the correct page if you enter some data into your form field and that is it. You can rely on the page's internal logic of sending request since you have separate tests for that.